# Properties of the determinant function

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $F$ be a field and $D$ a function on $n\times n$ matrices over $F$.  Suppose $D(AB)=D(A)D(B)$ for all $A,B$.  Show that either $D(A)=0$ for all $A$, or $D(I)=1$.  In the latter case show that $D(A)\neq 0$ whenever $A$ is invertible.

I understand the question after In the latter..., but I'm stuck on just understanding what this is asking.  Is this saying that suppose $D(A)\neq 0$ for a specific $A$, then $D(A)=D(AI)=D(A)D(I)=0$.  A contradiction since $D(I)\neq 0$?

Comment: You are right to look at $D(A)=D(AI)=D(A)D(I)$.  I do not follow why you decided to set this equal to zero or otherwise think that it should equal zero.  We wish to show that in the case that $D(A)\neq 0$ for some $A$ that $D(I)=1$.  Notice that $D(A)=D(A)D(I)$, or rearranged, $D(A)(1-D(I))=0$.  We said that $D(A)\neq 0$ so this implies that $D(I)$ must equal what...

Comment: You arrived at a contradiction.  This shows that two non-zero numbers multiply to 0

Comment: I had not arrived at any contradiction in my comment., I arrived at the conclusion that $D(I)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying that if there is at least *one* $A$ with $D(A) \ne 0$, then $D(I) = 1$.  This comes about as follows:

Note that if $D(A) \ne 0$ for some $A$, then

$D(I)D(A) = D(IA) = D(A), \tag 1$

whence since $D(A) \ne 0$,

$D(I) = 1. \tag 2$

Now if $A$ is invertible, we have

$AA^{-1} = I, \tag 3$

so

$D(A)D(A^{-1}) = D(AA^{-1}) = D(I) = 1, \tag 4$

which forces both

$D(A) \ne 0 \ne D(A^{-1}). \tag 5$

We also have

$D(I)D(I) = D(I^2) = D(I), \tag 6$

so the only two possibilities for $D(I)$ are $0$ and $1$.  If $D(I) = 0$, then

$D(A) = D(A) D(I) = 0 \tag 7$

for every $A$.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but $D(I)\neq 0$ since we have shown $D(I)=1$.

Comment: Right. The last sentence is just a slightly different take on the logic of it.  But I thought it was worth noting that $D(I)= 0$ or $D(I)= 1$ follows from $I^2 = I$.